Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
I am stuck with this error
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' (17).

I have tried several approach from here and here  like updating my build gradle here to VERSION_17 and VERSION_21 but the error still persist
compileOptions {
    // I have tried VERSION_17 and VERSION_21
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}

Anyone got a clue how to solve this,
app/build.gradle

build.gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.21-1.0.15" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.21" apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

gradle.wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


I fixed this with this steps

Check for update here



Android studio navigated to install new android studio here
After installing new android studio, replace old android studio with new one
Open your project and all dependency will be install.
if they are not install, invalidate your cache here and keep your finger crossed



You should set your project JDK version as 17.
You can find the settings inside And. Studio Settings under Build,Execution,Deployment / Gradle / Gradle Projects

